# Setup multiple startup pages in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, homepage

I know how to setup multiple start pages in Google Chrome but I want one of those pages to be its default new tab page which shows the thumbnails for 9 most visited pages.

Can this be done in Google Chrome?

Comment: Which operating system are you using? OS X or Windows?

Comment: I am google chrome beta on mac os x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can setup multiple home pages by going to Settings > Options and checking "Open the following pages" under Basic > On Startup.

You can add the URLs manually or select "Use current" to set all open tabs as homepages.

Since you want one of those pages to be its default new tab page which shows the thumbnails for 9 most visited pages, add the following URL: `chrome://newtab/`.

[image]

Comment: Cool always saw that but never realized it said 'Pages'

Comment: yep, i had it wrong at first myself. thought, it couldn't be done, but then i googled 'chrome new tab URL' :)

Comment: thnx Molly. This is great.